# MySQL querying error, I don't know why

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver

Ok so what I want to build:
A website where you login (I will do this later). There is a form where you submit your news report, which then goes into a MySQL database. This then gets displayed in a table view on the iPhone (that comes later).
As I mentioned, I get an 'Error querying database'. I have tried to fix it but I am new to MySQL and PHP, so I don't know what else to do.
I have this set up on a home server (WAMP).

My report.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Football Central News Report Submission Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Football Central News Report Submission Page</h1>
  <h2>Sumbit your football news report here</h2>
  <h3>CHECK FOR MISTAKES !!!</h3>
  <form method="post" action="report.php">
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" />
    <br />
    <label for="author">Author:</label>
    <input type="text" name="author" />
    <br />
    <label for="subtitle">Subtitle:</label>
    <input type="text" name="subtitle" />
    <br />
    <label for="body">Body:</label>
    <textarea name="body"></textarea>
    <br />
    <label for="image">Image:</label>
    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit your news report" name="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My report.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Football Central News Report Submission Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Football Central News Report Submission Page (Confirmation)</h1>

<?php
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $author = $_POST['author'];
  $subtitle = $_POST['subtitle'];
  $body = $_POST['body'];
  $image = $_POST['image'];

  $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'xxxxxx', 'news_reports')
    or die('Error connecting to database server.');

  $query = "INSERT INTO news_reports (title, author, subtitle, body) " .
    "VALUES ('$title', '$author', '$subtitle', '$body', '$image')";

  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die('Error querying database.');

  mysqli_close($dbc);
?>

<p>
-Thanks for submitting the form.<br />
-Your news report has been submitted to the database and should appear in the app shorty.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

AND FINALLY-My database structure (I can't post screenshots)
Fields:
report_id (primary key, auto-increment)
title
author
subtitle
body
image

P.S
For image /\ I am following "Head First PHP and MySQL", so it is the image name that is stored in the db, not the image (I haven't put this into the form, but I don't THINK this is the problem).

Sorry for the long post guys.
Luke

Comment: Do you have a question somewhere in there?

Comment: Simply `echo mysqli_error($dbc);` and you will know whats up

Comment: +1 for using the `mysqli` extension instead of the old `mysql` functions. But -100 for not doing any escaping of your input variables at all. Your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks, and will fail if any input contains quotes or other special characters.

Comment: You didn't mention the image field in the list of columns of the SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mismatch. You named 4 columns to insert to but you defined 5 values. Add the missing column.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO news_reports (title, author, subtitle, body) " .
    "VALUES ('$title', '$author', '$subtitle', '$body', '$image')"
```

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for that. I knew it would be something simple lol

And thanks for the tips on injections, I haven't reached that part in the book yet. But thanks for the heads up !

Comment: Ok so I might need some more help. I have (tried) improved the script a lot, but (using DreamWeaver) I am getting a syntax error but I can't see what's wrong. Where should I post the code ? It is 249 words.

Comment: after your query type `echo $query; exit;` and post it here.

Comment: Ok well now I have 2 new problems. I know what the problemsare but I don't know how to fix them. 1 is with a file upload and the other is with a contact form. Where should I post now ? Sorry guys.

Comment: if you have a new problem then ask a new question.